# How can I see the gateway connected individual device data in the IBM-watson-IoT dashboard?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, watson-iot

How can I see the gateway connected individual device data in the IBM-watson-IoT dashboard ? Is there any specific way see that?
Right now I am sending data as:

```
//publishing device events with deviceType 'Raspi' and deviceId 'pi01' using the default quality of service
gatewayClient.publishDeviceEvent("Raspi","pi01", "status","json",'{"d" : { "cpu" : 60, "mem" : 50 }}');
console.log('event published');
```

But I am not able to see this data stream anywhere in the IBM-watson-IoT dashboard. It's showing the event as received but no data stream of device "pi01".

When data is sent as:

```
gatewayClient.publishGatewayEvent("status","json",'{"d" : { "cpu" : 40, "mem" : 50 }}');
```

this means as gateway. It shows "received data" when I am creating the card. But I dont want this, I have a different device connected with the gateway, so I want the new device data in a different data stream.

Please let me know if I am doing it right, and if yes then where can I see all that data.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this in the Dashboard is in a Card. No other way in the Dashboard (though there are other ways outside of the dashboard).  Your code looks fine.  If you select your device in a Device centric card you can see the stream of values for just that gw-device in the properties or make graphs etc if they would help.  It is its own stream of data; should not be mixed up with any other device even if they share the same gateway.  Here is one gateway sending data for 2 devices using:

```
gatewayClient.publishDeviceEvent('SenseHat','sen-pi-xxx-gw' ,'event', 'json', '{"sugar":5, "salt":2}', 1);
gatewayClient.publishDeviceEvent('SenseHat','xx-gw-device' ,'event', 'json', '{"sugar":9, "salt":12}', 1);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, i have seen this . But i want my perious stream data also. Means in this it showing only last recieved data. what about the data i have send from begining when i have created that device. i want to see that data.   Please tell me what is the other way to see that? and how ? and also in device list when i am selecting any device of the gateway ,its not showing any sensor value.

Comment: You have to first store it somewhere - that isn't automatic.  See this and there are follow up ones as well: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/cloudant-nosql-db-as-historian-data-storage-for-ibm-watson-iot-parti/

Comment: i think i am making some mistake here while sending data. there should be another foramte of sending it. gatewayClient.publishDeviceEvent("Raspi","pi01", "status","json",'{"d" : { "cpu" : 60, "mem" : 50 }}');   if we need anymodification in this, becouse in recent event my fields are empity. if you can help in this

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that code.  And this now is going to a different topic - you have to follow SO rules.  Log a new Q, sames tags, include your code (not just the send, also how you connect but delete tokens/api keys!) and any messages you get back.  And a screenshot from the card where you expect to see the values arriving.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask